# Python reading .3gpp file

Tags: python, audio

I Have a huge list of audio files that I want to use in a learning algorithm for classifications. The problem is that these are all in .3gpp format and simply using

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
content = f.read()
```

throws an exception

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 695: character maps to undefined

I was looking for libraries that can read in .3gpp files but I don't seem to find any so now I'm asking the community here whether they know how to read in that format

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a package for reading .3gpp (audio) files too, and I found [moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) works well for me. Below is an example:

```
>>> import moviepy.editor as me
>>> ad_dat = me.AudioFileClip(r"test.3gpp")
>>> ad_dat.to_soundarray()
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       ...,
       [-0.00018311, -0.00018311],
       [-0.00012207, -0.00012207],
       [-0.00012207, -0.00012207]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read the audio file into an array? if so , you can try [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) to read the file, convert to numpy array and also export to other formats such as wav , mp3 etc. or play it. Details [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)'

I was able to get a .3ga sample file and convert to audioSegment using 'amr' option of ffmpeg (pydub utilizes ffmpeg in the backend).
If you want to read entire array, uncomment `np.set_printoptions`

Working code as below

```
import numpy as np
import sys

from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

#To print array fully
#np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

#Format conversion from .3ga
song = AudioSegment.from_file('example.3ga', format='amr')

#If you want to play file
#play(song)

#export to other format
song.export("example.wav", format='wav')

#Collect samples in array
samples = song.get_array_of_samples()
samples = np.array(samples)
print(samples)
```

Output .

```
>>python 3gaConverter.py 
[  6723  22419  30259 ... -21813 -22992 -21218]
```

If you simple want to convert to other formats, you can use ffmpeg directly

```
$ffmpeg -y -f amr -i ./example.3ga -f mp3 ./out.mp3

OR
$ffmpeg -y -f amr -i ./example.3ga -f wav ./out.wav
```

Comment: Won't work with 3gpp files however. Got error `pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1`